# Having issues with UPI deep-link from a web application for non-merchant initiated transaction

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, transfer, upi

I am working on a web application where I would like to enable UPI transactions between two UPI Ids (non-merchant UPIs) for non-business purposes. Example, transactions between friends to settle the balances for domestic spends.

I am able to generate the UPI intent uri as per the spec and able to open the UPI app, and able to initiate transaction with out any merchant id. However most of hte times transaction fails with below message and observed occasional successful transfers using same flow on retrying.

Here is the [Codesandbox link for a sample app](https://mlxj7.csb.app/) which I tried.

- How can I get more details about the failed transactions, and how are some transactions successful?
- Is it possible to allow p2p transactions between consumers without registering any business account (merchant id with NPCI)?

[image]

Comment: Been facing the same problem while developing native android app. Were you able to figure this out ? As far as i can tell it's issue with signing the intent with some code. Found this : https://web.archive.org/web/20200921110005/https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf
But its old and haven't been able to find any latest guidelines

Comment: Dinesh, did you get any solution for the same ?

Answer (score -1):

Pay using Intent is not allowed in P2P UPI App.
You can download the UPI Merchant App (P2M App), I tried in phonepe merchant App it working ok, but if Intent is not working on merchant Account, call customer care they will active it.